# vb.net setting data source to combobox

Tags: mysql, .net, database, vb.net, datasource

i want to set a data source to my combobox when i run there s no error  but it keeps showing zeros in the combobox

```
Dim cnx As New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;database=bdgeststock;userid=root;password=")
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = cnx.CreateCommand
        Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        If ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnx.Close()
        End If
        cnx.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT idf,(prenom + ' ' + nom) AS NAME FROM fournisseur "
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        cnx.Close()
        da.Fill(ds)
        da.Dispose()
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "idf"
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "NAME"
```

Comment: You don't have to use a dataset there, you can change it for a datatable- dataadapter.fill has an overload that takes a datatable, meaning you can `Dim dt as DataTable, Fill(dt), .DataSource = dt` - neater

Comment: Also possibly better to put your dataadapter in a Using block rather than calling dispose - easy to forget a dispose or miss calling it if an exception occurs but not a worry if it's in a Using - even if an exception happens VB will ensure the thing is disposed

Comment: Actually there were a lot more things that could be cleaned up in the code; see the code block I posted at the end of my answer (incase you already saw the earlier advice and haven't seen the edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your sql, and mysql is performing some sort of numeric addition on prenom plus nom and producing 0

Try

```
CONCAT(prenom, ' ', nom) as name
```

In your sql instead. I prefer using concat in most RDBMS for concatenating strings because is is more consistent with its behaviour on NULLs - in sqlserver, using the concat operator of plus on something like `'a' + null` results in NULL but in oracle `'a' || null` is `a` - in both the CONCAT behaviour is consistent

Here's a full code with all my recommendations:

```
Dim cnstr = "datasource=localhost;database=bdgeststock;userid=root;password="
Dim cmd = "SELECT idf, CONCAT(prenom, ' ', nom) AS nom FROM fournisseur "
Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd, cnstr)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "idf"
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "nom"
End Using
```

Tips:

- you don't need to mess around with the connection: dataadapter will create/open/close it for you
- use a datatable not a dataset
- use Using
- use the constructor of MySqlDataAdapter that takes a connectionstring and a command text- shorter and nearer in this case. I only use the constructor that takes a DbConnection if I'm manually enrolling multiple commands in a transaction etc

Answer (score 3):

For ComboBox data source you probably don't need heavy Data Set or DataTable - collection of plain object will do the job.

Another approach would be to move representation logic to the vb.net code and leave sql server to do persistence logic only.

```
Public Class Fournisseur
    Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String  

    Public Sub New(id As Integer, prenom As String, nom As String)
        Id = id
        Name = $"{pronom} {nom}".Trim()
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can create dedicated function to load data

```
Private Function LoadItems() As List(Of Fournisseur)
    Dim query = "SELECT idf, prenom, nom FROM fournisseur"

    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using command As New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
            connection.Open()
            Dim items = new List(Of Fournisseur)()

            Using reader AS MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim item As New Fournisseur(
                        reader.GetInt32(0),
                        reader.GetString(1),
                        reader.GetString(2)
                    )

                    items.Add(item)
                End While
            End Using

            Return items
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Then usage will look pretty simple

```
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Id"
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
ComboBox1.DataSource = LoadItems()
```

Comment: I disagree with nearly everything you wrote here; this is long winded and completely unnecessary for the limited use case presented. If you want a strongly typed class, use strongly typed datatables. We need to get away from incessant recommending that every trivial database access be done with a dataReader; do you create a tcp socket and manually implement the http protocol and JSON serialising every time you want to consume a restful web service? No. Then we shouldn't be so persistently low level when it comes to db access either.

Comment: @CaiusJard, no, but you use HttpClient and JSON serialiser to retrieve data into the objects and in this case MySqlCommand and MySqlDataReader playing role of the client and serialiser. You can wrap boiler code into a class or method.

Comment: @CaiusJard, this is a decision any developer can make to keep your business logic in database stored procedures and in UI operate with DataTables or keep it in vb.net code and treat database as simple storage device with minimum business logic in it.

Comment: No, the analogy was that MySqldataReader is about as low as you can get while still being in C#. HttpClient is quite a high level abstraction over a tcp socket. Had this answer recommended use of eg Dapper I would have less of a problem with it. We really need to move away from this mindset where we encourage newbies to use the lowest of the low when it comes to their data access, but everything else is sensibly high level, because it causes huge amounts of wasted time writing tedious code that can be better devolved to good libraries. We do it with nearly everything else.

Comment: @CaiusJard, sorry, but my main point were about using plain **vb.net** objects instead of heavy `DataTable`, especially in reading only cases such a data source for ComboBox. Feel free to populate plain objects via DataTable if you find it more convenient. With similar passion I would say that we really need to move away from this mindset where we encourage newbies to use `DataTable` everywhere. Instead concentrate them on finding right tool for the job and if it going to be `DataTable` - that totally ok, because developer is who making decision based on his knowledge at that moment of time

Comment: That's a reasonable point too; I should have been more explicit - totally on board with using a POCO, just not the bit where they fill it with a reader. Curious though, why do you opine that a DataTable is "heavy"?  Is there some authoritative reference that defines this weight in relative or absolute terms? DataTable has a huge amount of (unleveraged, here) functionality but at its heart it's a collection of object[]...

Comment: @CaiusJard, `DataTable` is "heavy" because of amount of functionalities it has to compare with plain vb.net object. I don't need "swiss army knife". One of the first cases when we moved from DataTables to plain object were performance during runtime and during reading code time. Note that in 95% of cases DataTable is not a performance bottle neck, but it were in our case. When I read a code which uses DataTable, I often found myself jumping back and forward between code which populates it and code which uses it to see what data is in there.

Comment: @CaiusJard, we don't use typed DataTables, because we found from the beginning that plain object provides us more freedom and allows us to separate application domain logic from it's persistence data schema.

Comment: Ok; just wanted to check — I agree datatable has a lot of functionality, but it should perhaps also be borne in mind that method code doesn’t inflate the size of an object, and that in this relatively trivial example of filling a combo with 20 items the overall weight difference of either solution is minor; I wouldn’t go as far to assert that it’s worth throwing datatables away in favour of POCO for this, especially when it increases the dev/maintenance headache (but that can be solved in other ways, that basically get back to eg POCO+Dapper, like DataTable+DataAdapter)

Comment: Indeed, it will always be the case that writing a dedicated minimal class from the ground up will allow more freedom than using a rolled solution with large amounts of unused functionality; the question is, on a case by case basis, whether it’s worth it

Comment: Right tool for the job ;)